# Avoiding confirmation email

Tags: email, inboundservices

I am sending out certain emails to contacts from my dev org. And when a contact replies to the sent email then my configured return address (please see screenshot attached) is proposed as default "To Address". This all works fine. 
But I have requirement, in which, I want to process the email sent by the contact using apex inbound handler. So, I changed my return address to configured salesforce email address. Please see the screenshot. But this will send a confirmation email to this salesforce email address and only after accepting this,it will be reflected in the org. Is there any way to avoid this confirmation email?

[image]

Comment: Did u miss adding the screenshot? Isn't this a one time confirmation?

Comment: @RichardN check now.

Comment: I have limited knowledge of the apex inbound handler. But am not sure why you are changing the address on this screen, Have you taken a look at this? http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/12/writing-an-inbound-email-service-for-salesforce-com/

Comment: I have already created inbound email handler which successfully processes any email comes to it. But I want all the emails inside salesforce to which contacts replied.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to "trick" Salesforce into letting you do this with your Inbound Email Service's failure response settings.

1. Ensure the `Accept Email From` setting of your Inbound Email Service does not contain any addresses with the salesforce.com domain in them
2. Set the `Unauthorized Sender Action` to "Bounce Message"
3. Check the `Enable Error Routing` box and use your personal email address in the `Route Error Emails to This Email Address` field
4. Attempt to change your email address in the My Email Settings menu as you are doing in the screenshot in your question

A confirmation email will be sent to the email service address (which will promptly bounce the email because it's from an unauthorized sender), and you should quickly receive a message at your personal address stating something along the lines of `554 Transaction failed: support@salesforce.com is not authorized to send emails to this service.`

The kicker is that *the message you receive will have the authorization email attached to it.* All you have to do is open the attachment, click on the verification link, and voila! Your change of address is confirmed.